# Rails & Javascript: strange 404s.... perhaps a crawler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler

This is perhaps a vague question, but it appears like some bot is crawling my site and doing it VERY poorly. It appears to be guessing IDs from my application js file and putting these into urls, for example:

```
Couldn't find Post with id=keypress
```

And even more strangely, the HTTP referrer is listed as application.js.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any ideas on how to stop these crawlers?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a legitimate crawler, you can stop it when by placing robot.txt file in your root domain directory - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

You would include the following text in the robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE/application.js
```

You can also add this tag to your page headers:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

If it is a malicious crawler, this of course will not stop it. There are other methods you can take for crawlers that do not respect robots.txt, but that depends on what web server you are using.

Comment: That would stop all crawlers though, including Search Engine crawlers, right? I doubt he'd want to do that. Better to exclude application.js from the crawler I think.